# Updating an object to an instance of a new object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular/typescript is it possible to update an instance of an object in a list to new object and have the change show in a bound list on the .html?

1. I get a Deck Of cards.
2. I draw three cards (display in HTML)
3. Draw one card and update the first card in the list to the new card that was drawn, but it's not getting updated in the HTML, even though if I view the objects the data has been updated.

**Code:**

```
// this works
this.Items[0] = this.Items[1]

//this does NOT work.
let newItem = new Item();
newItem.Id = x;
this.Items[0] = newItem; 


draw(deckId: string, count: number): Observable<Deck> {
  return this.http.get<Deck>(url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

drawThreeCards() {
   this.deckService.draw(this.deck.deck_id, 3).subscribe(data => {
   this.cards = data;
}

drawOneCards() {
    this.deckService.draw(this.deck.deck_id, 1).subscribe(data => {
    // Just as test I want to set the first card in the current
    // this.cards to the new card drawn

    let match = this.cards.find(x => x.Id == this.Items[0].code);
    match = this.data;
 }
```

Comment: in your `drawOneCards()` why cant you look from the already drawn card? that is from `this.cards` ?

Comment: it's not `this.data=match`?. BTW, NOT use `this.Items[0] = this.Items[1]`, you're asig the same object, if you want asing a different object use spread operator to make a copy: `this.Items[0]={...this.Items[1]}`